# I want to print the following format in java program for the pryamid

Tags: java

```
1**
2**
3***
4****
```

Till then I have got this snippet of code

```
public class triangles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {     
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {        
                System.out.print("*");
            }    
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean `1*` or `1**` ?

Comment: What is your question? Please be clear about what's wrong with the code/output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a requirements specification, not a question.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I mean by 1* @YCF_L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print your index before the loop :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    System.out.print(i);//<<----------Print the index i
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(i == 1 ? "**" : "*");//check if i == 1 then print 2 stars else 1
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

In case you mean **`1*`** you can replace `System.out.print(i == 1 ? "**" : "*");` with `System.out.print("*");`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add i index to print
here you go

```
public class triangles {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { 
           system.out.println(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {        
            System.out.print("*");
        }    
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't generate the output of the question

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 simplifies it:

```
public class triangles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {   
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, "*")));
        }
    }
}
```